# sharing a refresh token for an user in multiple browser

Tags: authentication, oauth, jwt, refresh-token

I am currently implementing login using jwt.

I stored access token and refresh token in cookies, verify the validity of refresh token, and reissue the access token.
Once logged in, a new access token and refresh token are issued and stored on the client side.
Here, the refresh token is stored in the server-side redis, and if it turns out to be a different token compared to the refresh token held by the client, the login is requested again.
I implemented it in this way considering the possibility that refresh token might be stolen, but there is one problem with this method. If the same user logs in from another browser or from another device, he or she must log in again with the browser he or she previously logged in with. Because whenever a new login occurs, the refresh token stored on the server is replaced by this.
What should I do in this case? It seems that there are cases where refresh tokens are stored on the client without saving them on the server, but in that case, did you not consider the possibility that refresh tokens might be stolen? We set HTTP only when saving to cookies. Is this enough to be safe? I'm looking forward to hearing from you.

The solution I came up with is to provide the refresh token of the server and save it to the client if you log in from another device and do not have the refresh token. In this way, you can use the same refresh token while using the existing refresh token comparison method, so you can ensure that you are the same user on multiple devices. Is that a good idea?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have a similar challenge. My Auth back end is AspIdentity  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore